# Virtual display for simple GPU development

Tags: verilog, simulation, linux, display

> Related: [Where to start when considering making a GPU?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15811/where-to-start-when-considering-making-a-gpu)

I'm a pretty strong programmer, but I'm very new to hardware design, so apologies if I use strange terminology.

My long-term goal is to write a custom GPU, but I'm starting out with a basic framebuffer to get comfortable with hardware design. Here's a rundown of what I'm expecting to do with my project:

1. Receive a frame of pixel data on a bus
2. Store frame in a stack on the hardware
3. Output frames at the monitor refresh rate

I can figure out #1 and #2, but I've never done anything like #3. I'm thinking the optimal development setup would be to have a virtual display that connects to the output pins of my design (VGA or DVI) and displays it in a window on my computer. I could probably do this with an FPGA and a small LCD, but I'm thinking it will be easier for development (esp. travelling) to have it all simulated.

Is there already a solution for this? If so, what can I search for to get more information about it? If not, what is the usual development setup for something like this?

I'm developing on Linux using Icarus Verilog, so a solution that works with that would be preferred.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any out of the box software that lets you drive a virtual display on your desktop via a verilog simulation. Honestly I think the easiest way for you to go would be to get a cheapo VGA monitor and an FPGA with a VGA port. Write simple directed tests that can be verified in simulation, but as for actually watching your design drive a display, you'll probably need to synthesize and run it in real time.

Comment: Seconded - outputting actual VGA will be much easier than trying to route it back into the computer. An osciliscope capable of handling video-speed signals (e.g. 100MHz) may be very useful if you can't get anything to appear.

Comment: @Tim - Dang, that's unfortunate. I guess it's not a very large market...

Comment: @tjameson Realize too that simulations are generally much slower compared to actual realtime execution. On a large design it might take a computer one or more hours to advance a verilog simulation by 1 millisecond. That's not going to make any computer graphics very impressive :). I think it's probably more fun anyway to drive a real monitor, travel/portability issues aside.

Comment: @Tim - Right. I was mostly looking for something I could do on an airplane or someplace where I don't have my dev stack. I guess this gets increasingly unrealistic the larger the design gets... Plugging it into a real monitor would definitely be much more fun though! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use PLI/VPI to call out to some C code - so rather than doing the top level pin driving, call a system task that stores the pixel in a software frame buffer and renders that to a window.

I've used the same technique for a UART recently - instantiated another uart with the TX + RX crossed over, and when the one in the testbench receives data - feed it to some C code with a system task that writes to a PTY (and vice-versa).

Given that the simulation probably won't run that fast, writing image files or binary data then post-processing might make it more useful.

Comment: This sounds quite reasonable, and would very quite useful for writing software-based unittests.